# i am trying to take all the value from jtable and add it to ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

hello i have method that take value from jtable and add it to ArrayList ,I am going to use the method to bufferWrite the text to srt file later but now i am saving the information inside arrayList

```
public static ArrayList<String> getTableSTimeData(){

ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){      
      data.addAll(getValueAt(i, 2));
      i++;
    }

return data;
```

}

error message is:

```
     error: cannot find symbol
          data.addAll(getValueAt(i, 2));
  symbol:   method getValueAt(int,int)
  location: class GuiInterface
1 error
```

netBeans are Suggest to create method getValueAt() but what is the content of this method 
some side information table are declared as global and this method are in the same class with

more code from the class

```
public class GuiInterface extends JFrame {
String[] columnNames = {"#", "Start", "End", "Translation column"};
public final JTable table;
DefaultTableModel cModel ;
public GuiInterface(String title){
cModel =new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
table = new JTable(cModel);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
    columnA.setMinWidth(10);
    columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
    TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
    columnB.setMinWidth(80);
    columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
    TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
    columnC.setMinWidth(80);
    columnC.setMaxWidth(90);

}//end of the constructor

 class Worker extends SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, Void> {
       private final String srtPath;
       private final JTable table;
       DefaultTableModel model;
        public Worker(String srtPath, JTable table) {
                this.srtPath = srtPath;
                this.table = table;
             }


     @Override
      protected DefaultTableModel doInBackground() {
     model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
    ArrayList<String> ends = ReadingFile.getFileEndingTime(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> starts = ReadingFile.getFileStartingTime(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> subs = ReadingFile.readSubtitles(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> lins = ReadingFile.ArraylineLengths(srtPath);
    for (int i = 0; i < ReadingFile.maxLine(srtPath); i++) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] {lins.get(i), starts.get(i), ends.get(i), subs.get(i)});
    }
    return model;
}
    @Override
     protected void done() {
    table.setModel(model);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
    columnA.setMinWidth(10);
    columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
    TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
    columnB.setMinWidth(80);
    columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
    TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
    columnC.setMinWidth(80);
    columnC.setMaxWidth(90);
}
}
/*
public Object getValueAt(int row,int column){


    return null;

}
  */  
public static ArrayList<String> getTableSTimeData(){

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();


        //for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){      
          Object val = table.getValueAt(2, 2);
            data.add((String)val);
        //}

    return data;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Maybe something to do with incrementing `i` in 2 places?

Comment: no he is saying create method getVlaueAt()

Comment: Where is `getValueAt()`?

Comment: Well, you are trying to use a method which doesn't exist. You can either write your own, or look at the docs for one that already does what you want.

Comment: it is outside the constrictor

Comment: Maybe you need to use `this.getValueAt()`? It is hard to tell without seeing more of your code (like where you defined getValueAt()).

Comment: no every one use this method but i don't know how to use this outside the constrictor

Comment: list.addAll accepts a Collection, make sure that you are supplying a Collection as the parameter in your method getValueAt.

Comment: If `getValueAt()` return String then use `add()` method instead of `addAll()`

Comment: ok maybe but not the answer

Comment: @user3571995 Are you not sure? on which object you are calling `getValueAt()` method?

Comment: Just post some more code for us to see. The questions we are asking aren't getting satisfactory answers.

Comment: @Takendarkk your answer is totally wrong i fixed the issue

Comment: I didnt post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `jtable.getValueAt()` where `jtable` is instance of `JTable`.

Sample code:

```
    public static ArrayList<String> getTableSTimeData(){

        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i=0; i < jtable.getRowCount(); i++){      
               Object val = jtable.getValueAt(i, 2); // value of ith row and 3rd column
               data.add((String)val);
            }

        return data;
    }
```

Please have a look at[JTable#getValueAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29) and [JTable#getRowCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getRowCount%28%29).

---

Please note according to your code your are taking all the values from 3rd column of each row.

**Why are you incrementing `i` two time in loop?**

Comment: i change it to cModel.getValueAt it works with no error but i did not try it

Comment: try what I have suggested `table.getValueAt()`.